# sql query joins multiple tables - too slow

Tags: sql, performance, join, hive, left-join

I am currently trying to join a few tables together (maybe join 2 additional more if possible) but with how my query is written right now, I cant even see the results with 3 tables

```
select t1.x, 
t1.y,
t1.z,
t4.a,
t4.b,
t4.c,
t4.d
from  t1
left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
left join t3 on t2.id=t3.id
left join t4 on t1.id2=t4.id
where t1.date between 'x' and'x'
and t1.city not in ('x')
and t3.column = x;
```

Is there a way to optimize this code to run faster and perhaps make it able to add more tables to it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1: you should specify your DBMS (oracle, mysql, sqlserver...). 2 : you should post your tables structure including indexes. 3 : you should post the result of the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query. After that we will be able to help you.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576)

Comment: Hard to tell without the explain plan, but if those tables are huge and have many to many relationship with the first table, you might want to use temp tables to store only the relevant data and columns before you do the joins. I am not sure if the `left join` on t2 and t3  is on purpose, but if it's not you could try `where exists` for t2 and t3 since you're not really pulling any columns from those tables

Comment: Without sample data and more explanation, your question doesn't make sense.  It basically says:  "I have some data I won't show you and a query that doesn't do what I want."  What's needed is an explanation of the data you have and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Ask 1 question per post. PS A [mre] re SQL performance includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has some logic issues that might help with the speed.

t2 is joined to t1 when they have the same id value.
t3 is then pulled in, if and only if, there was a row in t2 and it has the same value as t1 and t2.
Finally, in your where clause, the t3.column has to be x else it's filtered.

This means a row in t3 **has to exist**. Every t1 record that doesn't have a t2 record and  a t3 record will be filtered out with that where. Thus you don't need a left join, you need an INNER join.

```
select t1.x, 
t1.y,
t1.z,
t4.a,
t4.b,
t4.c,
t4.d
from  t1
inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
inner join t3 on t2.id=t3.id
left join t4 on t1.id2=t4.id
where t1.date between 'x' and'x'
and t1.city not in ('x')
and t3.column = x;
```

In some DBMS you can move the t3.column clause to the join command which can help filter out the rows earlier in the plan.

```
select t1.x, 
t1.y,
t1.z,
t4.a,
t4.b,
t4.c,
t4.d
from  t1
inner join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
inner join t3 on t2.id=t3.id and t3.column = x
left join t4 on t1.id2=t4.id
where t1.date between 'x' and'x'
and t1.city not in ('x');
```

My final advise is to take a close look at t2 to see if you really need it.  Ask yourself, is there a reason a row has to exist in t2 in order for me to get the right results?  ... because if t1.id = t2.id then t1.id = t3.id and you can eliminate the t2 table completely.